# SORT Operation in an Update Statement

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In the SQL below, why is my `Update` statement performing a `SORT` operation. The cost of the `SORT` operation is 41% and I would like to avoid it.

```
declare @m_table as  table (oh_job_cons_id varchar(36)) 

Insert into @m_table  
select top 100 oh_job_cons_id 
  from oh_job_cons with (nolock) 
    -- select * from @m_table 

Update j 
   set oh_locked_by_user_id = null,                           
       oh_locked_on = null                           
  from oh_job_cons j with (nolock) 
  join @m_table m on j.oh_job_cons_id = m.oh_job_cons_id
```

Comment: btw, forgot to mention, this is in T-SQL (2008 RS)

Comment: Is the table indexed by one or more of the values being updated?

Comment: My suspicion is that it's sorting at least one of the tables in your JOIN so that it can match them up.  Are the columns you're joining on indexed?

Comment: What is the definition of `oh_job_cons`? What does the plan look like? Does it have split and collapse operators too?

Answer (score 2):

The SORT in the update operation is probably due to the join constraint (@m_table m on j.oh_jobs_cons_id = m.oh_job_cons_id).

Particularly if the "oh_job_cons_id" column is not the primary key of the oh_jobs_cons table.

Comment: (...or is not indexed. A primary key, even a clustered primary key, is not the only structure that doesn't require a sort to facilitate loop or merge joins.)

Comment: Unlikely to get a merge join plan on a un indexed table variable without hints. The one row assumption pretty much always ensures nested loops.